# Which openbox config file to use in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

In Lubuntu 22.04, I found two config files for openbox at  `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` and `/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu/openbox/rc.xml`, respectively. (And neither of them are symlinks). So I wonder:

*Which one is the openbox config file actually used by Lubuntu? (or are they used by Lubuntu at all?)*

Also, if I want to change the config file, e.g. to [disable a shortcut key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715066), should I change one of the above files, or copy the `openbox/` folder above to `~/.config/`, and then edit in there? (, as suggested in the question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243088)

I searched around, but couldn't find a definitive answer except the fragments above. Also, by default, I don't seem to have `~/.config/openbox` folder.

Comment: Maybe it is also worthwhile to try to find people who know at [Lubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/latest)

Answer (score 1):

You will find an answer to your question here:
https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-22-04-1-lts-is-released/3528/7

Just create an `openbox` directory in `~/.config/`.